# html5 appcahe offline browsing not working fine in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, offline, html5-appcache

HTML5 appcache is not working in chrome as expected?

For example 
**http://html5demos.com/offlineapp**
when you load the above URL is will save locally,but when you refresh the page again it will not render properly.

MANIFEST file:
http://html5demos.com/html5demo.appcache
will cache the following files :-

1. images/shade.jpg
2. images/bin.jpg
3. /js/h5utils-offline.js
4. /css/html5demos.css

expect these files every other resources are not rendering when we refresh the page.

expected behavior:
All other resources(which are not in MANIFEST file) should load properly when user comes online.

but in Firefox this is working almost fine.

Why chrome is not working as expected ?
*It will be great if there is some perfectly working demo.*

Answer (score 0):

html5 appcache is at risk and may be removed: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/
http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/html/html5_html_manifest_attribute.php

Answer (score 0):

Non-cached resources will not load on a cached page. See Gotcha #5 from this article:

http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag

Using the network wildcard:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

...would fix this.